# PayPal IPN listener does not work when adding trial period to a subscription

Tags: paypal

I have a subscription based streaming site in which I am trying to implement a trial period of 3 days prior to the user being charged the monthly fee.

**THINGS TO KNOW**

- It works fine before implementing the trial code on the payment page (IE: a user is charged and their subscription automatically begins. Paypal IPN shows response)
- I'm pretty sure I need to add variables to the listener but this is where I am having issues.
- Providing below the unmodified payment code, unmodified listener code, paypal ipn response from unmodified code, modified payment code, and ipn response when using modified payment code
- Some of the info in the code provided has REMOVED to protect information

**UNMODIFIED WORKING PAYMENT SCREEN CODE**

```
   <!-- Buy button -->
    <form action="{{link}}" method="post" id="paypal-form-pay">
        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{account}}">
        <!-- Specify a subscriptions button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
        <!-- Specify details about the subscription that buyers will purchase -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{subscription.pack}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="{{id}}">
        
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{{subscription.currency}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="paypalAmt" value="{{subscription.price}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="subscription" id="paypalAmt" value="{{subscription.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" id="paypalValid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
        
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{{ url('wep_subscription_cancel',{"id":subscription.id})}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ url('wep_subscription_paypal_finish',{"id":subscription.id})}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{ url('wep_subscription_notify')}}">
        <input class="buy-btn" style="display:none" type="submit" value="Buy Subscription">

    </form>
```

**UNMODIFIED WORKING LISTENER CODE**

```
            $paypalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            $ch = curl_init($paypalURL);
            if ($ch == FALSE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

            // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
                
            $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
            $res = trim(end($tokens));

            if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0 || strcasecmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                $txn_id = !empty($request->get('txn_id'))?$request->get('txn_id'):'';
                
                if(!empty($txn_id)){
                    $payment_status = !empty($request->get('payment_status'))?$request->get('payment_status'):'';
                    $currency_code = $request->get('mc_currency');
                    $payment_gross =  !empty($request->get('mc_gross'))?$request->get('mc_gross'):0;
                    $item_number = $request->get('item_number');

                    $subscription = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Subscription")->findOneBy(array("id"=>$item_number,"method"=>"paypal","status"=>"unpaid"));

                    if (
                        $payment_status == "Completed" and 
                        $currency_code == $subscription->getCurrency() and
                        $payment_gross == $subscription->getPrice()
                    ) {
                        $subscr_id = $request->get('subscr_id');
                        $payer_email = $request->get('payer_email');
                        $payer_id = $request->get('payer_id');
                        $item_name = $request->get('item_name');
                        
                        $subscription->setEmail($payer_email);
                        $subscription->setStatus("paid");
                        $subscription->setTransaction($txn_id);

                        $started =  new \DateTime();
                        $expired =  new \DateTime();
                        $expired->modify('+'.$subscription->getDuration()." day");

                        $subscription->setStarted($started);
                        $subscription->setExpired($expired);

                        $em->flush();
                    }
                }

            }   
            return new Response("done"); 

    }
    public function finishAction(Request $request,$id){
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $subscription = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Subscription")->findOneBy(array("user"=>$this->getUser(),"id"=>$id));
        if ($subscription == null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");  
        }
        return $this->render('WebBundle:Subscription:finish.html.twig',array("subscription"=>$subscription));
    }
    public function paypal_finishAction(Request $request,$id){
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $subscription = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Subscription")->findOneBy(array("user"=>$this->getUser(),"id"=>$id));
        if ($subscription == null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");  
        }
        return $this->render('WebBundle:Subscription:paypal_finish.html.twig',array("subscription"=>$subscription));
    }
```

**IPM RESPONSE FOR UNMODIFIED CODE THAT WORKS**

> `mc_gross=0.01&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=3H4HMXYSVLVWL&address_street=6384 flathead avenue&payment_date=11:26:19 Mar 29, 2021 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=89122&first_name=Benjamin&mc_fee=0.01&address_country_code=US&address_name=Benjamin Halkum&notify_version=3.9&subscr_id=I-HY6W0PTGL3NB&payer_status=unverified&business=REMOVED.com&address_country=United States&address_city=Las Vegas&verify_sign=ArlJEh2PTclCmA4aNtb3eN2HF8lEAGBRRl4PvyzHc0gTKjP7ykq8080X&payer_email=REMOVED@gmail.com&txn_id=4W280838190693944&payment_type=instant&last_name=Halkum&address_state=NV&receiver_email=paypal@halkum.com&payment_fee=0.01&receiver_id=NFGUHZAMQSLPS&txn_type=subscr_payment&item_name=Test Only&mc_currency=USD&item_number=314&residence_country=US&receipt_id=0577-5054-4256-1714&transaction_subject=Test Only&payment_gross=0.01&ipn_track_id=79a7131ef33e4`

**MODIFIED PAYMENT CODE WITH TRIAL**

```
<!-- Buy button -->
    <form action="{{link}}" method="post" id="paypal-form-pay">
        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="{{account}}">
        <!-- Specify a subscriptions button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
        <!-- Specify details about the subscription that buyers will purchase -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{subscription.pack}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="{{id}}">
        
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{{subscription.currency}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="a1" id="paypalAmt" value="0.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="subscription" id="paypalAmt" value="{{subscription.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="p1" id="paypalValid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="D">
        
        
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="{{subscription.currency}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="a3" id="paypalAmt" value="{{subscription.price}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="subscription" id="paypalAmt" value="{{subscription.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" id="paypalValid" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
        
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{{ url('wep_subscription_cancel',{"id":subscription.id})}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ url('wep_subscription_paypal_finish',{"id":subscription.id})}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="{{ url('wep_subscription_notify')}}">
        <input class="buy-btn" style="display:none" type="submit" value="Buy Subscription">

    </form>
```

**MODIFIED CODE IPN RESPONSE MESSEGE**

> `amount1=0.00&amount3=6.99&address_status=unconfirmed&subscr_date=11:39:54 Mar 29, 2021 PDT&payer_id=3H4HMXYSVLVWL&address_street=REMOVED&mc_amount1=0.00&mc_amount3=6.99&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=89122&first_name=Benjamin&reattempt=1&address_country_code=US&address_name=Benjamin Halkum&notify_version=3.9&subscr_id=I-G1VY47ASJ8C4&payer_status=unverified&business=REMOVED.com&address_country=United States&address_city=Las Vegas&verify_sign=AhM9chhyQTrOGTRyOPkwcY26Rcv3AhiXC3kA9XVfl3desynG0cKTMHw4&payer_email=contact@indystars.co&last_name=Halkum&address_state=NV&receiver_email=REMOVED.com&recurring=1&txn_type=subscr_signup&item_name=Monthly*&mc_currency=USD&item_number=318&residence_country=US&period1=1 D&period3=1 M&ipn_track_id=bfcdb7a2bc514`

Comment: Preston gave me a good starting path in terms of what to look at. 

For re-writing the listener to account for the trial period, does anyone have any good starting points or links to examples that deal in this? I've searched through the PayPal developer documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The sample in your "MODIFIED CODE IPN RESPONSE MESSAGE" appears to be what is expected, so this is a matter of updating your listener to handle a different payload when there is a trial period. Among other things, there will be no transaction yet and hence no `txn_id`, so you will need to write code for the new situation.

Comment: Appreciate it @Preston. I am a novice at this, can you explain why when I add the trial period in, it not longer outputs a txn_id? I would think, it would stay the same for the most part but the mc_gross would include the 2 amounts together.

Comment: With your trial period the initial amount is 0.00  , so there is no PayPal transaction until 3 days later....

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Unfortunately, I still have yet to work out the kinks in it automatically updating when a payment renews, so that's a struggle for another day.

What I am thinking though from your post here is, if I set my trial as say, $0.99 for the first week then X amount going forward, that should theoretically work until I can figure out how to best rewrite the listener

Comment: As an update, my theory was correct.

I can at least now offer a discounted trial.

Comment: Bear in mind there is a much newer version of PayPal Subscriptions: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ -- which uses a better JS button and is designed to work with Webhooks rather than IPN for event updates

Comment: I actually tried to implement that last night. The flow worked fine, able to go through, make the payment, subscription started in PayPal.

However, it wouldn't trigger the account to activate.

Now, that's PROBABLY on me not setting up the webhook correctly as I believe I just placed my IPN Notify URL in the field.

Comment: While similar in purpose, Webhooks are their own thing and you need to specifically subscribe to the events you want to receive for each cliient ID, and parse it with code that actually reads the JSON-formatted Webhook data, which is not at all the same as an IPN message